# How to check storage path for a Snowflake Table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We know show create table in hive gives storage path. Checking how to find a storage path for a snowflake table. I don’t see show create or desc table giving a storage path for a table.

Comment: Why do you need the storage path? You can not access or manipulate data files

Answer (score 1):

One of the main advantages of Snowflake Data Platform is automatic storage handling:

> [Key Concepts & Architecture](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/intro-key-concepts.html#database-storage)
>
> Database Storage
>
> When data is loaded into Snowflake, Snowflake reorganizes that data into its internal optimized, compressed, columnar format. Snowflake stores this optimized data in cloud storage.
>
> **Snowflake manages all aspects of how this data is stored — the organization, file size, structure, compression, metadata, statistics, and other aspects of data storage are handled by Snowflake. The data objects stored by Snowflake are not directly visible nor accessible by customers;** they are only accessible through SQL query operations run using Snowflake